# How to get specific Array value from an Array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'd like to get a specific array data from an array I've get from this code :

```
$user       = $request->instance()->query('user');
var_dump($user);exit;
```

And the result is :

> array(1) { ["user"]=> object(App\Models\User)#332 (27) {
>   ["fillable":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=>
>   string(8) "username" [2]=> string(5) "email" [3]=> string(8)
>   "password" [4]=> string(5) "token" } ["hidden":protected]=> array(2) {
>   [0]=> string(8) "password" [1]=> string(14) "remember_token" }
>   ["casts":protected]=> array(1) { ["email_verified_at"]=> string(8)
>   "datetime" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql"
>   ["table":protected]=> string(5) "users" ["primaryKey":protected]=>
>   string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int"
>   ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15)
>   ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false)
>   ["attributes":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=>
>   string(14) "Manchesteriyah" ["username"]=> string(14) "manchesteriyah"
>   ["email"]=> string(24) "manchesteriyah@gmail.com" ["facebook"]=>
>   string(37) "https://web.facebook.com/xkionna" ["phone"]=> NULL
>   ["email_verified_at"]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(60)
>   "$2y$10$IrqHE1JfyH0bJ0XD/Hjy.efLg95y/buTIir0PuXcOqDb1yCSS69Oe"
>   ["image"]=> NULL ["description"]=> NULL ["role"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["token"]=> string(20) "ymsJxEtFnxdPBWYwlYFw" ["member_expiration"]=>
>   string(19) "2019-07-08 20:33:29" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2019-06-08 20:30:25" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-06-08
>   20:33:29" } ["original":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(3)
>   ["name"]=> string(14) "Manchesteriyah" ["username"]=> string(14)
>   "manchesteriyah" ["email"]=> string(24) "manchesteriyah@gmail.com"
>   ["facebook"]=> string(37) "https://web.facebook.com/xkionna"
>   ["phone"]=> NULL ["email_verified_at"]=> NULL ["password"]=>
>   string(60)
>   "$2y$10$IrqHE1JfyH0bJ0XD/Hjy.efLg95y/buTIir0PuXcOqDb1yCSS69Oe"
>   ["image"]=> NULL ["description"]=> NULL ["role"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["token"]=> string(20) "ymsJxEtFnxdPBWYwlYFw" ["member_expiration"]=>
>   string(19) "2019-07-08 20:33:29" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2019-06-08 20:30:25" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-06-08
>   20:33:29" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=>
>   bool(true) ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" }
>   ["rememberTokenName":protected]=> string(14) "remember_token" } }

What I'd like to get is the username value, I've tried some solution like this :

```
$user->username
```

but it give me error like this :

> Trying to get property 'username' of non-object

How to fix this? Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$user` variable seems to be holding an array containing 1 element, not the User itself. You must first retrieve the User object from the array and then access the *username* attribute.

```
$user = $request->instance()->query('user')['user'];
var_dump($user->username); exit;
```